# Finding a volume over an elliptical region

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am trying to find the volume of the region $0\leq z \leq e^{4x^2+25y^2}$

where $4x^2+25y^2\leq 1$ and $x^2/25 +y^2/4\geq 10^{-3}$.

I have identified the regions in the $x,y$ plane as 2 ellipses. So I made the substitution, $x = 5r\cos\theta$, $y = 2r\sin\theta$ so now $x^2/25+y^2/4 = r^2$.

So the region in the x,y, plane is now circular, and the region D in the x,y, plane can be written as $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{10^{-3}}^{1/100}$ but this is not giving me the right answer.

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one V=$\int_0^{2\pi } {\int_{\sqrt {{{10}^{ - 3}}} }^1 {\int_0^{{e^{{r^2}}}} {rdzdrd\theta } } }$

Comment: how did you get this?

Comment: r is varying from ${\sqrt {{{10}^{ - 3}}} }$ to 1 and z is varying from 0 to $e^{r^2}$